# How to change the fontFamily of the labels and remove the grid in chart.js

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

I would like to customize the labels in chart.js, but don't seem to find the right way. Where do I need to put the styling options? What goes around it? 
Is there a way to remove the Grid lines all together?

```
options: {
  scale: {
    gridLines: {
      display: false
    },
    scaleLabel: { 
      fontColor: 'green',
      fontSize: '24px',
      fontFamily: "Montserrat"
    },
  ticks: {
    maxTicksLimit: 1,
    display: false,
    },
  }
},
```

I would expect the font color to change to green and get bigger, but it does not effect the font at all. 
The same goes for the GridLines. I would expect that both vertical and horizontal lines would be removed, but the vertical Lines stay unaffected.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D3B6.png)

Answer (score 1):

The `radar` chart uses a [Linear Radial Axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html). That documentation details all of the customization you have available for your chart axis.

**Font**

To configure your font as you have it above, you would want to have those settings on your options under the `pointLabels` property:

```js
options: {
  scale: {
    pointLabels: {
      fontColor: 'green',
      fontSize: 24,
      fontFamily: "Montserrat"
    }
  }
}
```

*As a note, the `fontSize` property is supposed to be a number, not a string.*

**Angle Lines**

There are two different settings for the axis lines (`gridLines` and `angleLines`). The `angleLines` are the lines that radiate out from the center of the chart and what you are wanting to additionally hide. To hide the `angleLines`, you would want to do the following:

```js
options: {
  scale: {
    angleLines: {
      display: false
    }
  }
}
```